# R Multiples plot in a single varible

Tags: r, plot

Hi I have the next code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(BCxyz[,1], BCxyz[,2], main="Bray-Curtis 1:2", pch=20, cex = 3, col=c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow")[Metadata$SampleType])
plot(BCxyz[,1], BCxyz[,3], main="Bray-Curtis 1:3", pch=20, cex = 3, col=c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow")[Metadata$SampleType])
plot(BCxyz[,2], BCxyz[,3], main="Bray-Curtis 2:3", pch=20, cex = 3, col=c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow")[Metadata$SampleType])
```

in this way I get a figure with 3 plots, so I just want to add the figure (with 3 plot in it) in a single variable, something like :

```
figure1 <- (mfrow=c(1,3)........)
```

and each time that I call figure1, open 3 plot in a single figure !!!!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "single figure"? As far as external processes are concerned, the triple-plot is seen as a single plot that has encoded within it the lines/dots/... for multiple data with lateral separation. Also, normally base-graphics are not stored in a variable (unlike `ggplot2`-based plots, as an example), so what do you intend/need to do with `figure1` once this triplet-plot is stored in it?

Comment: `figure1 <- function() {par(); plot(); ...}; figure1()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `recordPlot` to save the current plot and recall it later.

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(1) ; plot(2); plot(3)
figure1 <- recordPlot()
# view then close the plot window, just to prove that redrawing it works

figure1             # redraws it when interactive on the console
replayPlot(figure1) # same thing
print(figure1)      # indirect, calls replayPlot
```

The last two commands have the same result on the console, but if you are going to "replay" the plot programmatically (e.g., within `{...}` code-blocks or functions), you should use the `replayPlot` function directly. The reason just `figure1` works by itself on the console (no `print` or `replayPlot`) is that `figure1` is of class `"recordedplot"`, and the base-R `grDevices:::print.recordedplot` S3 method calls `replayPlot` directly.