# Return a par(mfrow) as a result of a function

Tags: r, function, plot, return

I made a function calculating something and I want to return a `par(mfrow)` with 3 plots that I calculate inside the function but I don't know how to do that. Out of the function the `par(mfrow=c(1,3))` followed by the 3 plots works fine. What's the syntax for doing something like that?

My syntax is the following:

```
myfunction<-function(){
  return(par(mfrow=c(1,3)))
  persp(x,y,z)
  contour(x,y,z)
  image(x,y,z)
}
```

Comment: So you want it to just plot the three plots? If so you can just drop the `return()` part in what you have.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59795945. That is, use `recordPlot`. (I cannot close this as a dupe of that one yet, as the answer is not accepted yet.)

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies..I looked for a similar question but i didn't find one that's why i opened this.The solution with recordPlot works fine.. :)